# Clearance from diferential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the next diferential equation: $\frac{dv}{dt} = g -\frac{c}{m}v$

Given $v(0)=0$, the solution is: $v(t) = \frac{gm}{c}(1-e^{-\frac{c}{m}t})$

Then they ask me to obtain a formula for $c$ in terms of the other values, assuming that I have the values of $m$ and $v(t)$, but I can't clear $c$ from the function of the solution.

Comment: Numerically.${}{}{}$

Comment: Need to use some sort of Lambert W function...